# Falla al usar instrucción ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Buenas tengo una consulta donde muestro cantidades y nombres de areas, todo esta bien se ejecuta normal pero al momento de usar `ORDER BY` la consulta dura casi 6 minutos.

Consulta sql:

```
WITH primero AS(
SELECT
Servicios.IdServicio, 
Servicios.Nombre,
CASE WHEN FuentesAtencion.IdFuenteAtencion=2 THEN COUNT(FuentesAtencion.IdFuenteAtencion) ELSE 0 END AS cantidadP1,
COUNT(IdServicio) AS cantidadP2
FROM Atenciones
INNER JOIN Asistencia on Atenciones.IdAtencion=Asistencia.IdAtencion
INNER JOIN FuentesAtencion on FuentesAtencion.IdFuenteAtencion=Atenciones.IdFuenteAtencion              
INNER JOIN Servicios on Servicios.IdServicio=Atenciones.IdServicio
WHERE Atenciones.Fecha BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31' AND Atenciones.IdTipoServicio IN (2,4)
GROUP BY Servicios.IdServicio, Servicios.Nombre, FuentesAtencion.IdFuenteAtencion
)
SELECT 
IdServicio,
Nombre,
SUM(cantidadP1) AS cantidadP1,
SUM(cantidadP2) AS cantidadP2
FROM primero
GROUP BY IdServicio, Nombre
--ORDER BY IdServicio ASC ------>AQUI AGREGO ESTO Y SE LENTEA TODO
```

RESULTADO:

```
IdServicio  Nombre      cantidadP1  cantidadP2
70          AreaP20     0           2
446         AreaP450    0           1
103         AreaP110    24          586
105         AreaP115    0           777
390         AreaP301    1           1007
69          AreaP15     0           3748
```

Entonces algo esta mal o a que se debe esto?

Comment: O sea, no es necesario que esté mal, ordenar es un proceso costoso a menos que haya un índice. Puedes postear el plan de ejecución de la consulta sin `ORDER BY` y con `ORDER BY`?

Comment: @Lamak cuando no uso ORDER BY la consulta demora 0 segundos pero si lo uso dura casi 6 minutos, he agregado el resultado

Comment: por curiosidad, has probado a poner el ORDER BY dentro del parentesis del WITH? es que me da la sensacion de que te puede estar haciendo el primer select varias veces, debido a que los datos del primer select estan desordenados y los tiene que recalcular dentro de la consulta...

Comment: @Lamak se refiere a que ejecutes esto: [Mostrar el plan de ejecución estimado](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-the-estimated-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver15) y no el resultado de la ejecucion del query.

Comment: Gracias @OrlandoDeLaRosa, pero en verdad lo mejor sería obtener el plan de ejecución real (no el estimado)

Comment: Cierto, copie y pege el que no era: [Mostrar un plan de ejecución real](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Respecto a la consulta **dentro** del `With`, ¿cuántos registros devolvería sin el group by y cuántos con el group by?

Comment: Otra duda: Si ordenas por otra columna, pasa lo mismo? Por ejemplo `ORDER BY Nombre ASC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Independientemente de lo que te ha solicitado @Lamak que deberías de hacer, le estuve echando un ojo a tú consulta, y creo que hay muchas cosas que puedes mejorar.

Primera opción, menos válida, pero que seguro que mejora tú tiempo de respuesta, con la consulta explicita tal cual la has pegado.

```
WITH primero AS(
SELECT
Servicios.IdServicio, 
Servicios.Nombre,
CASE WHEN Atenciones.IdFuenteAtencion=2 THEN COUNT(Atenciones.IdFuenteAtencion) ELSE 0 END AS cantidadP1,
COUNT(atenciones.IdServicio) AS cantidadP2
FROM Atenciones
INNER JOIN Servicios on Servicios.IdServicio=Atenciones.IdServicio
WHERE Atenciones.Fecha BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31' AND     Atenciones.IdTipoServicio IN (2,4)
GROUP BY Servicios.IdServicio, Servicios.Nombre, Atenciones.IdFuenteAtencion
), segundo As(
SELECT 
IdServicio,
Nombre,
SUM(cantidadP1) AS cantidadP1,
SUM(cantidadP2) AS cantidadP2
FROM primero
GROUP BY IdServicio, Nombre
) 
select * from segundo
order by IdServicio Asc
```

Como puedes observar, te he quitado dos conjuntos de la tabla de expresión común "primero", ya que no los utilizas para nada, por tanto sobran. Y luego he encerrado la segunda agrupación en otra tabla de expresión común para obtener una select de esta segunda tabla de expresión común y aplicarle el order by.

Segunda opción.

```
;With primero as
(
  SELECT
    Servicios.IdServicio, 
    Servicios.Nombre,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Atenciones.IdFuenteAtencion=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cantidadP1,
    SUM(1) AS cantidadP2
    FROM Atenciones
        INNER JOIN Servicios on Servicios.IdServicio=Atenciones.IdServicio
    WHERE Atenciones.Fecha BETWEEN '20200101' AND '20200131' AND     Atenciones.IdTipoServicio IN (2,4)
    GROUP BY Servicios.IdServicio, Servicios.Nombre
) SELECT * FROM PRIMERO
Order by IdServicio
```

Si en la tabla de expresión común, utilizas una agrupación, entonces ya puedes calcular todo en el primer conjunto. Por cada fila sumas en cantidadP1 si le corresponde un 1 y sumas 1 a cantidad P2. Y la fecha del filtro en formato Iso, para no tener nunca problemas.

Comment: Gracias, me resulto bien tu segunda opción. No tengo mucho experiencia en sql pero me ayudo bastante

Comment: De nada. Un placer poder ayudar.